# Proving this function to be identically 0

Tags: complex-analysis, problem-solving

This question was asked in my complex analysis quiz and I was unable to solve it.

> If $\Omega= \{ z: Re(z) >0 \}$ and f is a bounded holomorphic function on $\Omega$ with $f(n) = 0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N} $ then show that $f(z) =0$ for all z $\in \Omega$ .

I am sorry but I will not be able to provide anything as attempt as I am absolutely clueless on how to approach this problem in both exam time and while trying again . Kindly believe me and tell me which result should I use.

Thank you!!

Comment: I understand if you are clueless. You  should then tell us what results you know, what material you learnt before this quiz, etc., because leaving us empty handed is not going to help you.

Comment: Do you really mean homomorphic?  That’s a term from algebra, and doesn’t seem to belong here.

Comment: Please show your attempt, I will show my **full** solution.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3830772/conclusion-about-a-holomorphic-function-which-is-not-bounded/3830887#3830887

Answer (score 4):

Consider the function

$$\varphi(z)=\frac{z-1}{1+z}; \varphi:\Omega\leftrightarrow \mathbb{D}$$

Defining $g(z):=f(\varphi^{-1}(z))$, we have translated the problem to a bounded holomorphic function on the unit disk.

It is easy to see that the  zeros of $g$ are of the form $\frac{n-1}{1+n}$. Thus, applying the Blaschke condition (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blaschke_product)) , we obtain that $g\equiv0$. It easily follows that $f\equiv 0$

Comment: Please do not give a full solution to the question which do not show any attempt. Also, this question is a duplicate https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3830772/conclusion-about-a-holomorphic-function-which-is-not-bounded/3830887#3830887

Comment: I'd say, given the timestamps, that the question you linked it a duplicate and not the other way around

Comment: @Caffeine I am not able to understand what will Blaschke condition do here?

Comment: @Tim The Blaschke condition is: given a sequence of points in the unit disc $\{a_n\}$, there exists a bounded holomorphic function different from zero such that $\{a_n\}$ is the set of its zero iff $\sum (1-|a_n|)<\infty$. Since here the sum is $\infty$, $g$ has to be zero

Comment: @Caffeine:(+1) for your generosity to others.