# Conclusion about a holomorphic function which is not bounded

Tags: complex-analysis, examples-counterexamples

This question is part of an assignment which I am trying.

> Question: 1.Show that there is no bounded homomorphic function f on the right-half plane which is 0 at point 1,2,...and 1 at √2.

2.What if ' bounded ' is ommited?

I have done 1 by Lioville theorem but can there exists a such a function in 2?

I am not sure about that.
Can anyone give example or tell which result to use to prove its existence?

Thanks!!

Comment: A similar result was asked just a few minutes ago, but there is no answer yet. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3830723/proving-this-function-to-be-identically-0

Comment: For second part take $f(z)=\frac {\sin (\pi z) } {\sin (\pi \sqrt 2)}$.

Comment: Please show how you did the first part.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Function is holomorohic and bounded and hence must be constant. As it assumes 0 infinitely many times so it must be zero identically and hence can't assume√2. Is it fine?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy will keep an eye on  question given by you thanks!!

Comment: That is wrong. Liouville's Theorem applies only to holomorphic functions on the entire complex plane. It is not valid for the right half plane. $e^{-z}$ is a bounded hlomorphic function on the right half plane.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy yes that was a mistake!!

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Do you think it is better to answer the first part here right now? I mean I have an answer, but not sure whether I should post or not.

Comment: @0-thUser The first part is a duplicate  so I don't think an answer is required here.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy But there no answer in the link shared by you. Are you talking about some other link?

Comment: @0-thUser Well, you have deleted your answer in that link and I don't know why.

Comment: I deleted it because Op has not shown any attempt even after asking. but here the OP showed some attempt.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proving this function to be identically 0](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3830723/proving-this-function-to-be-identically-0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $\frac{\sin(\pi z)}{\sin(\pi \sqrt{2})}$ is equal to $0$ for $z = 1, 2, ...$  and equal to $1$ for $z=\sqrt{2}.$
Furthermore, it is holomorphic everywhere and unbounded. To see the latter, let $z=it$ and let $t$ be an arbitrary large real number.

Answer (score 1):

**I do another part since one part is already answered. I show there is no non-zero holomorphic function $f$ defined on open right half plane such that $f(n)=0$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$.**

> Let $\Bbb D:=\{z\in\Bbb C:|z|<1\}$ and  $g:\Bbb D\to \Bbb D$ be non-constant holomorphic function and let
> $\{a_j\}_{j=1}^\infty$ be the zeros of $g$, counting multiplicities.
> Then, $\displaystyle \sum_{j=1}^\infty\big(1-|a_j|\big)<\infty$.

To prove this, without loss of generality assume each $a_j\not=0$. Write $g(z)=c_jz^j+c_{j+1}z^{j+1}+\cdots$ with $c_j\not=0$. For $n\geq 1$ define  $$g_n(z):=\frac{g(z)}{\displaystyle z^j\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{a_k-z}{1-a_kz}}\text{ for }z\in\Bbb P\backslash\{a_j\}_{j=1}^\infty.\text{ Here}, \Bbb P=\Bbb D\backslash\{0\}.$$ By Riemann removable singularity theorem we can extend each $g_n$ on $\Bbb D$. By maximum modulus principal, $|g_n|\leq 1$. In particular, $\displaystyle |c_j|=\big|g_n(0)\big|\leq \prod_{k=1}^n|a_k|$ for each $n\geq 1$. Since $c_j\not=0$ we have $\displaystyle \prod_{j=1}^\infty|a_j|$, hence $\displaystyle \sum_{j=1}^\infty\big(1-|a_j|\big)<\infty$. converges.

> Now, to conclude **first part of your question** consider the fact that $\psi:\{z\in\Bbb
>  C|\text{Re}(z)>0\}\ni z\longmapsto \frac{1-z}{1+z}\in \Bbb D$ is
> bi-holomorphic and $\psi^{-1}=\psi$.

That is say consider $\psi\circ f\circ \psi^{-1}:\Bbb D\to\Bbb D$ after multiplying $f$ by suitable constant so that $f:\{z\in\Bbb
 C|\text{Re}(z)>0\}\to\Bbb D$.